# trouble on using lb-services (Loopback - Angular JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, local-storage, loopbackjs

I'm using lb-services from Angular JS SDK to create my default service, and currently, I have some trouble in logout & rememberMe function.

I'm following this tutorial : [Angular Javascript SDK](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK) & [Loopback getting started intermediate](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/tree/master/client) , and the way I create my authentication is as same as the example, with some adjustment to apply them in my application.

I'm not sure how to describe it, but here's some of the code for my logout & remember function

in my *stateProvider*, I have this kind of state as my root application

```
.state('app', {                
url:'/',
abstract: true,                
views:{                    
'bodyLogin': {templateUrl : 'views/login/body.html',              
controller  : 'BodyController'},                    
'bodyMain': {templateUrl : 'views/main/body.html',                        
controller  : 'BodyController'}}            
})
.state('app.mainUnreg', {                
url:'home',                
views: {                    
'content@app': {                        
templateUrl : 'views/login/home.html'                    
}}})
.state('app.mainReg', {               
 url:'mainMenu',                
views: {                    
'header@app': {                        
templateUrl : 'views/main/header.html'                    
},                    
'sidebar@app': {                        
templateUrl : 'views/main/sidebar.html'                    
},                    
'middle@app': {                        
templateUrl : 'views/main/home.html'                    
},                    
'footer@app': {                       
templateUrl : 'views/main/footer.html'                    
}},                
controller: 'HomeController'})
```

*index.html*

```
<div ng-if="!loggedIn" ui-view="bodyLogin" class="site-wrapper" ui-sref-active="app.mainUnreg"></div>        
<div ng-if="loggedIn" ui-view="bodyMain" ui-sref-active="app.mainReg"></div>
```

so, if I haven't not logged in, I will enter to bodyLogin, which means I will show my login template, and otherwise, if I have logged in, I will enter to bodyMain

I have succeed to logged in and enter to my main page, but on here, and it should be have been authenticated, because in my bodyController,

```
.controller('BodyController', [..., function(...){    
//this line is to check whether the user has been authenticated or not
if(Account.isAuthenticated() === false) {        
$scope.loggedIn = false;}    
// ------------

if($scope.loggedIn === false){        
$scope.layout = 'login'; 
$state.go('app.mainUnreg');
}   
else{$scope.loggedIn = true; 
$scope.layout = 'styles'; 
$state.go('app.mainReg');    
}}])

.controller('LoginController', [..., function (...) {    $currentUserId = Account.getCurrentId();    
$scope.$stateParams = $stateParams;    $scope.loginData = {};    $scope.doLogin = function() {                AuthService.login($scope.loginData)        
.then(function() {            
$scope.loggedIn = true;                     
location.reload();        });    };}])

.controller('LogoutController', [..., function(...) {
AuthService.logout()
.then(function() {
console.log("Logging out . . .");
$scope.loggedIn = false;
$state.go('app');     });     }]);
And some additional service beside lb-services.js to handle my authentication,

function login(loginData) {
        var params = { rememberMe: loginData.rememberMe };
        var credentials = {
            email: loginData.email,
            password : loginData.password
        };
        return User
            .login(params, credentials)
            .$promise.then(function(response){                $rootScope.currentUser = {...};
                console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
            },
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
    function logout(){
        return User
        .logout()
        .$promise.then(function(){
            $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        });
    };
```

I think, with this kind of code, especially I have checked with

```
if(Account.isAuthenticated() === false){...}
```

and succeed to enter my main page, I have successfully logged in and authenticated, haven't I?

But, if I tried to put `ng-show="Account.isAuthenticated()"` in the top div of my main page `app.mainReg` , my page can't be show, yet it means that my account haven't authenticated, even the loopback have successfully save my token, user id, and rememberMe boolean in local storage, like this

```
$LoopBack$accessTokenId = ....
$LoopBack$currentUserId = ...
$LoopBack$rememberMe = true // automatically become true?
```

So, do anyone know how to solve this problem? I think the problem is on the authentication.

I'm quite confused with this one, I have tried to search for solution, yet I could find any.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized why I couldn't use rememberMe function, that's just because I made a silly mistake, by putting " ; " after my logout function in my additional services

And after several testing, It seems that my problem was inside my state provider. I tweaked my controller and my state provider and finally it has been work successfully.